# Storing array in database to prevent database hit in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, optimization

I am using the [acts_as_taggable](http://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem, which has a method tag_list, which produces an array of tags, but requires an SQL call. I have been research optimization and am curious if it would be good storing this list as an array in the database to prevent needing an SQL call when I simply want the names of the tags. I know arrays in a database is not good design, but it ultimately prevents queries?

Every time a program (what is tagged) is displayed, I want to display the list of tag names. I need nothing besides their names.

Am I being overzealous with avoiding the database or would this be a great help to making the site more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are being overzealous.

If you put an array in the db - you'd still need to fetch it from the db. The time-difference between these two sql-calls is negligible - and the array-deserialization will probably make it slower.

Also - Rails will automatically cache the sql- query so if it's identical it will already not bother to make the sql call.

If you really want to speed it up - why don't you cache the page-fragment that contains the tags?

Comment: I am looking into all sorts of caching as well as limiting SQL calls. I'm gonna leave the question out for a few days and see if there are other answers, otherwise I'll accept this one.